# Quicksort implementation error

Tags: c++, algorithm, quicksort, divide-and-conquer

I was trying to implement quicksort. But the control seems to be never exiting the quicksort function. Any help would be much appreciated.

A few pointers:

1. I am using the first element as the pivot. I know much better and efficient techniques exist to choose the pivot, but this is not about that.

2.The 'k' variable in the partition function is the pivot element.

As far as I know, the problem is with the partition function, since I have tried debugging it various times.

Also, this is not a Homework question. I was trying to implement the algorithm after having learnt it by myself.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void swap(int *a,int *b)
{
    int temp;
    temp=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=temp;
}

void readarray( int a[],int n)
{
    cout<<"Enter elements for the array\n";
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>a[i];
}

void printarray(int a[],int n)
{
    cout<<"Elements are as follows\n";
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";

    cout<<endl;
}


int partition(int low,int high,int a[])
{
    int i,j,k;
    i=low;
    j=high;
    k=low;

    while(i<=j)
    {
        while(a[i]<a[k])
            i++;

        while(a[j]>=a[k])
            j--;


        if(i<=j)
        {
            swap(a[i],a[j]);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }

    if(i>j)
        swap(a[k],a[j]);

    return j;
}

void quicksort(int low,int high,int a[])
{
    int k;
    if(low<high)
    {
        k=partition(low,high,a);
        quicksort(low,k-1,a);
        quicksort(k+1,high,a);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a[20];
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter the size of the array\n";
    cin>>n;
    readarray(a,n);
    cout<<"Before sorting\n";
    printarray(a,n);

    quicksort(0,n,a);

    cout<<"After sorting contents are\n";

    printarray(a,n);

    return 0;
}
```

In the main function I have tried using both the quicksort(0,n,a) and quicksort(0,n-1,a). Neither worked.

Comment: Prefer to use references instead of pointers in your swap function

Comment: This shouldn't compile, because you're passing `int` values like `a[i]` to the swap function instead of the expected pointer values like `a+i`.

Comment: @Lee other reason to use references :)

Comment: are you sure `while(a[i]<a[k]) i++;` eventually stops? I think it can go outside a[] very easily.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Agreed. Further I wouldn't use a `low`, `high`, and `ar[]` in my function, Rather I would simply do the right math on the caller-side and use `ar[]` and `len` going into each partition. The code just feels cleaner (imho).

Comment: If you're going to use C++, better use `std::swap` instead of reinventing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is problem with your partition routine, see comments:

```
int partition( int low, int high,int a[]) {
   int i, j, k;
   i = low; 
   j = high;
   k = low;

  while ( i < j )
 {
  while( a[i] <= a[k] ) // Move i while item < kth element
   i++;
  while( a[j] > a[k] ) // Move j while item > kth element
   j--;
  if ( i < j )
   swap(&a[i],&a[j]); //Pass address of elements
 }

swap(&a[low],&a[j]); // j is final position for the kth element (viz.the pivot )

   return j;
}
```

Call quick sort routine using:

`quicksort(0,n-1,a);`

Comment: Good work for stopping it stepping outside the array bounds... I get -858993460 1 2 for the array 2, 1, 3 with this though

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me. Could you please tell me how using the references made it work and why the absence of references was causing an error in the first place?

Also when we are passing array elements as arguments, isn't the address sent on its own. The why do we need to send it via a reference explicitly?

Comment: @Piyush I used your `swap` version only `&a[i]` is address of a[i] element. If you want you can use `void swap(int& a,int& b){int temp;temp=a;a=b;b=temp;}` and then while calling drop off the `&` sign. Now this version of swap uses reference. For more details google `call by value`, `call by reference` and passing arguments using pointers

Comment: Alright thank you. Can't believe I made a mistake in the swap function.